# Can I auto-generate a new spreadsheet from an existing spreadsheet without breaking HIPAA?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hipaa

I'm currently collecting client data through a Google Form into one massive Sheet. I want to create individual Sheets, in addition to the conglomerate, for every new client, as soon as the new form response is collected. Is Google Script HIPAA-compliant? Is there another way to automatically generate a new sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. Is Google Apps Script HIPAA compliant? Hard to say, a programming language can't really be said to be 'compliant'. However, the application software that you build with it should be if its being used in a Healthcare context.

The following article provides a clear overview of the criteria an application needs to meet to be considered HIPAA compliant: 
https://www.truevault.com/hipaa-compliance.html

It basically boils down to 4 key points and I quote:

> - *You must put safeguards in place to protect patient health information.*
> - *Reasonably limit use and sharing of protected health information to the minimum necessary to accomplish your intended purpose.*
> - *Have agreements in place with service providers that perform covered functions. These agreements, called Business Associate Agreements (BAAs) ensure that service providers (Business Associates) use, safeguard and disclose patient information properly.*
> - *Procedures to limit who can access patient health information, and training programs about how to protect patient health information.money penalties.*

The question you have to answer is can you effectively build a tool with GSuite's platform that meets these requirements. I think its possible, not trivial, but possible.